# What determined today's primitives in programming?

Tags: primitive

I am very new to programming so correct me if I am wrong, I am just trying to piece together what exactly programming is and why it is the way it is. So I understand that programming is ultimately like writing a “recipe” for the computer. You write these recipes with primitives. (Which in baking is like eggs, flour, milk, etc). Basically, the elements that make up recipes.

Now back to the real question, what would you consider  these primitives? would they be variables, data types, loops, if-statements, etc?

and if those are the “primitives” what determined what those primitives are? 
I hope I am not confusing anyone with my explanation of my question.

Comment: This is probably off-topic (for various reasons), but you could look at assembly and very early compiled languages to get a sense of where things came from.

Comment: A primitive is a type or function that can't be broken down into smaller pieces within that language, such as (in C) the `int` type, `if` statement or `+` operator. Eggs, flour and milk are not examples of primitives: for cooking purposes you regularly break them down into shell+white+yolk, wheat starch + gluten, or skimmed milk + cream. Different languages have different primitives: it's not useful to talk about the origin of C syntax and Lisp syntax as one.